# Text in view randomly truncated

Tags: cakephp, text, cakephp-2.0, truncate

I'm using CakePHP2 to display some datas and retrieve it with an AngularJS app.
In my controller I set a `$data` and a custom view like this :

```
$this->layout = null;
$data = "HELLO WORLD ! THE SKY IS BLUE.";
$this->set('data', $data);
$this->render('/Elements/customview');
```

In my `customview.ctp` I have just a `echo $data;`

The problem is that in my browser, I got this :

```
HELLO WORLD ! THE S
```

The text is truncated for no reason.

If I change the `$data` to `HELLO WORLD !`, in the view I can only see `HE`

Have you an idea about why my text is randomly truncated like that ?

Comment: what is the output of `pr($data)` in the view?

Comment: @bill I have this with pr : `HELLO WORLD ! THE SKY IS `

Comment: This might be unrelated but I believe the correct syntax for disabling the layout is `$this->layout = false;`

Comment: I can not reproduce your problem. I put same code on controller and customview.ctp and it works correctly. I think there is something you are not telling us ;)

Comment: It's not "randomly" truncated, 11 chars are missing both time which seems to indicate some processing some place. Try naming it something else like `$test` instead of `$data` and debug in the view. Does it happen?